# ValueError when searching for values in two dataframe columns with Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using Python for data cleaning and would like to identify outdated items in an EXCEL file that I am reading to a pandas dataframe.

The columns in the input file are:

[image: Structure of input file]

In this file, "place_new" and "inst_name" randomly contain place names which ought to appear in "place_name", so I want to check both "place_new" and "inst_name" for occurrences of place names from a separate list called "places_new".

My code looks like this:

```
# find "hidden" places in two different rows and add values to PLACE_NAME column
            
    for p in places_new:
        print(p)
        try:
            p_add=f[f["place_new"].map(lambda place_new: p in place_new) & f["inst_name"].map(lambda inst_name: p in inst_name)]
            print(p_add)
            f['place_name'] =(f['place_name'].map(str) + "/" + p_add)
            
        except KeyError:
            print("Key Error")
            continue
            
        print(f)
```

This raises the following error:

```
ValueError: Columns must be same length as key
```

I cannot figure out what triggers this error and would appreciate your help.

Comment: please provide a self-contained example, including input and expected output data.

Comment: check the shape of p_add, probably it doesn't have the same length as f dataframe